ORA-01652: SELECT from view@dblink
I getting an ORA-01652: unable to extend temp... when
SELECT * FROM view@dblink

The tables inside view is very big.
Is there a oracle hint /* */ or another way not to touch temp tablespace ?

Could you paste the complete ORA error?

did you try to limit the number of rows?
like:
SELECT * FROM view@dblink order by 1 OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY


I disagree with the downvote on this answer. There is a decent chance that adding a row limiting clause will change the execution plan in a way that also reduces the amount of temporary tablespace. For example, the execution plan may change from a hash join to a nested loop, which will possibly require less space to store intermediate results. The overall runtime might increase, but that might be an acceptable tradeoff. On the other hand, row limiting may not be possible - perhaps a hint like /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */ would work better. And this solution avoids solving the root cause.

The view contains a SQL query that likely is doing hash joins, sorts, aggregation, etc.. which requires temp space if it overflows the maximum permitted PGA per process. This is quite normal. In some cases a hint can be used to change join type (e.g. force nested loops) or px distribution method or join order to reduce memory demand but this may cause performance problems of its own. Nobody could recommend any such thing without seeing your query and knowing your data, which isn't feasible in this forum.
You will have to reach out to the DBA of the remote database you are querying and ask them to take a look on their end. It may (usually is) a bad plan, such as one with a Cartesian join or hidden partial Cartesian (many-to-many join) that balloons intermediate result set rows which then feed into a later hash join (where the temp space will be much larger than it should be), but it can also simply be too much data for the sizing of an undersized assigned temp tablespace, and a DBA would need to enlarge the tablespace in that situation.
